# Не удаляются кнопки в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я пытаюсь создать 3 кнопки через цикл `for`, и потом по нажатию на любую из них она удалялась.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
r=Tk()
a="del"
for i in range(3):
    b=Button(r, text=a, command=lambda : b.pack_forget())
    b.pack()
r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы лямбда-функция "запоминала", какой виджет ей нужно удалить, нужно явно передать ей этот параметр (в качестве значения параметра по-умолчанию):

```
for i in range(3):
    b = Button(r, text="del "+str(i))
    b.config(command=lambda widget=b: widget.pack_forget())
    b.pack()
```

Сделал в две строки, так как переменная `b` на момент создания lambda-функции еще не определена.

Comment: Спасибо но можно вопрос зачем делать "widget=b" какая разница я конечно протестил но я серовно не понимаю етого

Comment: @Gleb, если без этого, то все кнопки будут пытаться удалить кнопку, которая была создана последней (которая последней осталась лежать в переменной `b`), но не сами себя.

Comment: но почему именно последнию. Значение b менялось точно также как и widget

Comment: @Gleb, b менялось, но в итоге лямбда функция будет ссылаться на глобальную переменную b, в которой после окончания работы цикла будет лежать последняя созданная кнопка.

Comment: о спасибо я понял но почему оно ссылаться на глобальную переменную b а не на то значение которое ей было задано?

Comment: @Gleb, ну, так работает Python. Если в лябмда-функции используется внешняя по отношению к ней переменная, то в момент запуска функции будет происходить обращение к самой переменной (в ее текущем состоянии), а не к ее значению в момент создания функции. Поэтому приходится использовать трюк со значением параметра по-умолчанию, тогда в параметр как раз попадает значение переменной момент создания лямбды. Как-то так.

Comment: @Gleb, вот разъяснение в документации Python: [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: да спасибо а с def будет точно такаяже ситуация

Comment: @Gleb, функция, созданная через `def`, создается только один раз, ну и если внутри будет использоваться, например, переменная `b`, то и использоваться будет значение переменной в момент вызова функции (а не в момент создания).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
r = Tk()

buttons = []
for i in range(3):
    b = Button(r, text="del" + str(i), command=lambda x=i: buttons[x].pack_forget())
    buttons.append(b)

    b.pack()

r.mainloop()
```